# How to match to a number of any length, not just a digit

Tags: regex

How do I match to a number of any length, if its a one digit number I can use `\d` but if its any length do I have to use the non-word `\W` ? Or can I use [0-max] ?

Comment: You can use like : \d+ or [0-9]+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

`{n,m}` generic quantifier, matches at least n times at most m times. When m is omitted it matches any amount

`?` is short for `{0,1}`, i.e. makes the preceding object optional, means match 0 or 1 times

`+` is short for `{1,}`, i.e. repeats the preceding object 1 or more times

`*` is short for `{0,}`, i.e. repeats the preceding object 0 or more times (matches also on an empty string!)

But be careful, when you are searching for `\d{1,2}`, it will normally (depends on the language and method you use) also match on "123456". Then you need to have a look at [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
\d+
```

That means match at least one (`1..n`) digit character.